# How to Select Audio Output Device in VLC player?

Tags: mac, vlc-media-player, audio-output

On Mac OS, is there a way to select the audio output device?

I want to change the audio output from internal speakers to my Sennheiser USB headset.

Comment: Related question that will hopefully have more success: http://superuser.com/questions/459809/how-to-send-vlc-player-audio-to-headphones-rather-than-pc-speaker

Answer (score 3):

Once you open VLC, Play the Video >> Go to Audio >> Audio Device >> Select the Device Name you want to use as speaker

Answer (score 2):

If mac VLC is the same as windows, then go to tool --> preferences --> audio and then look for the audio output dropdown.

Comment: It contains Default, Dummy audio output, HAL AudioUnit output, File adio output. Which one shall I select?

Comment: well, I'm answering 22 hours too late but it's HAL output or it's not listed at all. If it's not listed, I'm at a loss (not a mac expert). Hopefully someone with more knowledge glances at this topic.