# How to send VLC Player audio to headphones rather than PC speaker?

Tags: windows-7, audio, vlc-media-player, windows-media-player, audio-output

Similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/263169/how-to-select-audio-output-device-in-vlc-player), except I'm on Windows 7. That question also has no accepted answer, and the answer doesn't work for me.

I've tried all the different "Output Module" settings in the Audio section of the preferences in VLC Player, and still the sound comes out of my PC speaker instead of the 3.5mm audio jack, where my headphones are plugged in.

Headphone audio output works fine for every other application I've used, including Windows Media Player.

How can I get VLC Player to send its audio output to my headphones instead of to the PC speaker?

Comment: For both Mac OS and Windows 7, you have to makes sure that you have the USB headset driver installed and loaded.

Comment: @AlexW, I'm not using a USB headset, just the 3.5mm audio jack. Would it still make a difference?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that this problem was unique to VLC.

Comment: It may be a bug: http://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/6510 You can try closing VLC, plugging in headphones, and then opening VLC.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This solution ([from here](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=99379)) resolved the issue:

1. Open Tools/Preferences and at the bottom of the list,under "Show settings" switch from Simple to "All".
2. Under Audio, Expand and select "Output module" and change Audio output module to "Win32 waveOut extension output".
3. Under "Output module" select "Waveout".
4. Select Audio Device. In the dropdown, select your output used for your headset and click save.
5. Restart VLC.

Note that in my case the restart of the VLC application was definitely required! It may also mean that when I previously tried various different settings without restarting VLC, the changes may actually have worked after restarting VLC.

Answer (score 0):

Just had same issue and for me and after pairing my device used these steps :

Select :

Control Panel -> Sound -> Manage Audio Devices

Under Playback tab set bluetooth device to default :

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To use VLC Player on your computer with only headphone sound output or headphone and computer speaker audio output do this:

- open vlc with your movie ready to play
- <kbd>Right mouse button</kbd>on the vlc interface anywhere on the movie
- select *audio* then *audio device*
- you have 3 options *default*, *headphones and speakers*, and *communication headphone*
- select *communication headphones*

This should route the audio to your headphone jack.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser, we prefer standard english answers with some formatting, not one paragraph of swwweeeeet BADASS rant. Thank you.